# Perl: Thread creation failed: pthread_create returned 11

Tags: multithreading, perl

My code is like below:

```
my $tcount :shared = 0;

while( $message = $msgQueue->poll()){
    if($tcount < 4){
        Logger::log(3, "Number of active threads : ".$tcount." processing incomming message");
        threads->create(processData,$message,createMsgId());
    } else {
        Logger::log(2, "Maximum number of threads reached. Waiting");
        sleep 1 until $tcount < 4);
        threads->create(processData,$message,createMsgId());
    }
}

sub processData {
    $tcount++;
    # do something
    $tcount--;
    threads->exit();
}
```

As per my understanding I am not creating more than 4 threads at a time. However, after running this script for a while I get:

```
Thread creation failed: pthread_create returned 11
```

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `pthread_create` returns `EAGAIN`, it means

> Insufficient  resources  to  create another thread, or a system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.  The latter case may occur in two ways: the RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via setrlimit(2)),  which limits  the  number of process for a real user ID, was reached; or the kernel's system-wide limit on the number of threads, /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max, was reached.

Well, at least on my system.